# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing this error while run the script.

```
(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. )
```

This is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.set_headless()

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="home/appadmin/geckodriver")
browser.get('http://google.com/')
browser.quit()

version installed :
Mozilla Firefox 90.0
selenium==3.141.0
Python 3.6.10
geckodriver 0.29.1
```

Any one can help me to resolve this error.

Comment: In geckodriver.log i received like            1626417861662   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:38465
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
1626417984375   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:33657
1626418498261   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:37423
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
1626419057925   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42209

Comment: I want to install any thing?